# How to re-run BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I need to catch error during `DoWork` and if the error is of some type- re-run the same BachgroundWorker. Already tried to cancel it and call `RunWorkerAsync()` during `Completed` event, but no luck(exception appears saying that my backgroundworker object was canceled).

Comment: wouldn't handling the error inside the backgroundworker DoWork make more sense?

Comment: I do its handling, but it continues to Completed event handler anyway... May be GOTO is the way?

Comment: @nihilist, now it sounds like a control-flow problem inside DoWork. It is perfectly possible to restart some action after catching an exception. DoWork is just another method.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, call DoWork(this, null) inside DoWork event handler?

Comment: @nihilist, at least call it with `DoWork(sender, e);` but it really shouldn't be necessary. Without a sample of your code it's hard to tell why you wouldn't need a `goto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the Bgw remains in the Error/Canceled state until the Completed event has finished.

A few options:

- restart the logic inside DoWork
- start *another* Bgw from the completed event.

A Bgw itself is not expensive so there is little point in reusing a specific instance. The threads come from the ThreadPool.

Comment: You are right, it really remains in canceled state. I cant use another object for creating bgw, because there is checking if bgw.IsBusy on exactly that bgw object on, lets say, button clicks. So i consider to use goto in DoWork to start it over. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Or should i call DoWork inside of DoWork?(hate goto :))(pity, but i cant test the code right now, thats why im asking such things.. :()

Comment: Suppose it is called backgroundWorker1, then just do: `backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker(); ... // attach events ; backgroundWorker1.RunAsync();`